# Can I use storage directory to storage files

Tags: php, laravel

I have quick question. Is good idea to keeps files uploaded by user in app/storage directory in laravel?
I think about users avatar and other images.

What exactly I should keep in storage directory? May I save files under this path?

Comment: I use this folder for system logs and data. I think you can use for images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per http://laravelbook.com/laravel-architecture/

I put my images in the public directory.

**/public/**

The only folder seen to the world as-is. This is the directory that you have to point your web server to. It contains the bootstrap file index.php which jump-starts the Laravel framework core. The public directory can also be used to hold any publicly accessible static assets such as CSS, Javascript files, images and other files.

**/app/storage/**

The storage directory is used as temporary file store for various Laravel services such as sessions, cache, compiled view templates. This directory must be writable by the web server. This directory is maintained by Laravel and you need not tinker with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store files wherever you want, that is entirely up to you. If you wish for them to be web accessible at all times, then put them into `/public/`.

If for example the files need to be restricted and only available via certain pages, say for example, for members of the site, without allowing hotlinking, you could store them in `/app/storage/` and then load them through using headers and `file_get_contents()`.

The structure is entirely yours to play with, do as you wish.

Comment: Yeah but there is a best practice way of doing things. No?

Comment: Depends on the purpose.

Comment: I disagree but whatever. I think best practices are best practices. It's almost like hacking the the core of a CMS or Framework. I know I exaggerate. ;)

Comment: Well, no it does depend. If the purpose is for the images/files to be accessible to the web at all times, then the best practise would be to put it in `/public`, but if they're supposed to be secured behind something, then `app/storage` would be best.

Comment: Putting it in storage wont make it safe if its still accessible via a url.

Comment: No it's not because the directory root for the web would be `public` so `app/storage` wouldn't be accessible, hence its purpose.